# Função Recursiva no TypeScript retornando Array com Objetos Dinâmico

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursão

Sou iniciante no TypeScript e tb no JavaScript, portanto confesso não ter muito conhecimento da linguagem, portanto, vou descrever meu problema.

Tenho a seguinte tabela em um banco de Dados PostGres:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, uma estrutura simples onde um registro referencia o outro em um estrutura pai-filho hierárquica.

O que preciso fazer é uma função no typescript que seja recursiva que me retorne um array com objetos mais ou menos assim:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,    
    filhos: [
      {
        id: 11,
        filhos: null
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        filhos: [
          {
            id: 121,
            filhos: null
          },
          {
            id: 122,
            filhos: null
          },
          {
            id: 123,
            filhos: null
          },
          {
            id: 124,
            filhos: null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    filhos: [
      {
        id: 21,
        filhos: null
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        filhos: null
      },
      {
        id: 23,
        filhos: null
      }
    ]
  }    
]
```

Reparem que o Objeto Pai contem todos os seus filhos dentro, e assim sucessivamente.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que você tenha recebido um array com os dados do Postgres, da seguinte maneira:

```
var arr = [
  {id: 1, idPai: null},
  {id: 2, idPai: null},
  {id: 11, idPai: 1},
  {id: 12, idPai: 1},
  {id: 21, idPai: 2},
  {id: 22, idPai: 2},
  {id: 23, idPai: 2},
  {id: 121, idPai: 12},
  {id: 122, idPai: 12},
  {id: 123, idPai: 12},
  {id: 124, idPai: 12}
];
```

Um exemplo de código pra percorrer o teu array e montar a hierarquia recursivamente:

```
var resultado = [];

function teste(arrEntrada, arrSaida){
    for (let i = 0; i < arrEntrada.length; i++) {
        let item = arrEntrada[i];
        let obj = {
            id: item.id,
            filhos: []
        };
        let filhos = arr.filter(elemento => elemento.idPai === item.id);
        teste(filhos, obj.filhos);

        arrSaida.push(obj);
    }  
}

teste(arr.filter(elemento => elemento.idPai === null), resultado);
console.log(JSON.stringify(resultado));
```

Você pode facilmente adaptar para outros tipos de retornos.

*Este exemplo está em Javascript puro, mas pode ser usando dentro do teu TS sem problemas*

[Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/pjvmhwas/16/) o fiddle para teste.

Answer (score 2):

Um jeito bem simples apenas utilizando o método [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, idPai: null },
  { id: 2, idPai: null },
  { id: 11, idPai: 1 },
  { id: 12, idPai: 1 },
  { id: 21, idPai: 2 },
  { id: 22, idPai: 2 },
  { id: 23, idPai: 2 },
  { id: 121, idPai: 12 },
  { id: 122, idPai: 12 },
  { id: 123, idPai: 12 },
  { id: 124, idPai: 12 }
];

let resultado = arr.filter(pai => {
  pai.filhos = arr.filter(filho => filho.idPai === pai.id);
  return pai.idPai === null
});

// Apenas para demonstrar a saída!
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(resultado, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```